# How do I set up a battery backup for an outdoor sump pump

Tags: sump-pump

I saw a post from 2016 asking this question with two options
A water tight container for the battery backup 
Or an internal ups for it
It’s 2020 and I’m curious if there’s anything better now.
My pump is ~80’ from our house so the backup would need to be outside.
I have a generator that I’ve successfully used but if we’re not home or on vacation.

Comment: It's 2020 and electricity still works the same way; if you need electricity when the regular source is gone, you either store it chemically (battery or fuel) or live without it. How large is your sump pump? How long do you want it to run if the power fails?

Comment: 1/2 hp sump pump - needs to run 3-6 hours depending on the amount of rain.

Comment: ...you're going to want one of those expensive auto-start generators, and I hope you have piped natural gas to run it from, if not having the sump pump running will cause expensive damage while you are away. Consider the expense of the one while looking at the expense of the other, or redecorate so you can wash down the tiles in the part of the house that floods when power is out. If you want a LOT of exciting 2020 expense, you could get a PowerWall, but then an autostart generator may look cheap.

Comment: I agree, a generator that starts automatically when needed is the only reasonable way to power a sump for 6 hours. Battery technology has changed, but not that much, so the cost of having AND MAINTAINING batteries sufficient for running that motor for that long is not inconsequential. "Power Wall"? Sure, just take out another mortgage...